# Use more than one or opreator in a boolean expression

Tags: java

For example, in the code blow, one of the result was 1 1 0 1. Apparently the `(c==0)` Boolean was true, this loop should not stop its work. So I was just wondering how java syntax read this Boolean expression.

```
int a=0,b=0,c=0,e=0;
    do {
        a++;
        b+=(int)(Math.random()*2);
        c+=(int)(Math.random()*2);
        e+=(int)(Math.random()*2);
        System.out.println(a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+e);
    } while (a==0|b==0|b==0|e==0);
    System.out.println("final"+a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+e);
```

Comment: If a is `0` or `b` is `0` or `b` is `0` or `e` is `10`. No short-circuit, because you used `|` instead of `||`.

Comment: You wrote `b==0` two times instead of `c==0`

Answer (score 1):

Your loop condition is `a==0|b==0|b==0|e==0`. Thus, you are never checking `c==0`. Changing the condition to `a==0|b==0|c==0|e==0` should work.

Also, I recommend to use the `||` OR operator, which is the boolean OR as opposed to the bit-wise OR `|`.

Thus, your loop condition should be `a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0 || e == 0`.

Comment: I am sorry I typed the wrong code, I found my problem few seconds after I post my question.

Comment: Good to hear the problem is solved. Also, welcome to stackoverflow. You might be interested in [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). For example, you should accept a helpful answer to indicate that the question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You never used c==0 in your while loop. So, if any one of a, b and e becomes zero, the loop will break.

And java and other language read boolean as T and F combination.

- T T T T =T
  -T T T F = T
  -...........
  -...........
- F F F F = F

so if all are false, then it will be true.